# How to set grid view column height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and don't have much experience.
I am trying to develop an android app using flutter and this is my previous app design.

[image]

And I'm also able to successfully make grid view in flutter but the column height is the problem. Is their anyone who can help me with my flutter code.

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     hi(){

    }
     return new Scaffold(

         appBar: new AppBar(
           actions: <Widget>[],
                title: new Text("milla"),
              ),
       body: new Container(


         child: new Center(

            child: new GridView.count(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              childAspectRatio:1.0,
              crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 400.0 ? 3 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1000.0 ? 5 : 4,

           // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
           // horizontal, this would produce 2 rows.

           crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
           // Generate 100 Widgets that display their index in the List
           children: new List.generate(100, (index) {

             return  new Column(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

                 verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                 children: <Widget>[


                   new Center(

                     child:  new Image(


                         image: new NetworkImage('https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg?raw=true')
                     )
                   ),
                   new Expanded(child: new Text("apple2")), new Expanded(child: new Text(
                   'Item $index',
                   style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                 )),new Expanded(child: new Center(child: new Row(
                     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

                     children: <Widget>[new Text("+",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),),new Text("1"),new Text("-")])))]
             );
           }),
         ),
        ),
      )
     );
   }
 }
```

And this is my output.[image]

How to set column height?
When i'm trying to add new view, it's showing this error 
"Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 21 pixels on the bottom."

Comment: You have to adjust your aspect ratio.

Comment: I have to show grid in 1:1 (width:height) ratio but height should have additional 100 pixels extra. eg. How can i do? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Put this instead of

```
childAspectRatio:1.0 to  childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight)

var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 final double itemHeight = (size.height) / 2;
 final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
```

It works fine in my code to set height and width of Gridview

Comment: How will we know the itemHeight if it dynamic

Comment: Hi this solved my problem. Been trying to solve it for hours. Thanks. But can you explain how it works?

Comment: I have to show grid in 1:1 (width:height) ratio but height should have additional 100 pixels extra. eg. How can i do? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You might try this:

```
GridView.count(
   crossAxisCount: 2,
   childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 400,
   children: <Widget>[...]
);
```

Comment: what is 400? is it item height?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
childAspectRatio: mediaQueryData.size.height / 1000,
```

where

```
MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

I saw this code somewhere and looks ok to me.

Answer (score 2):

Maintain
`childAspectRatio: with MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/600`
if this didint work change 600 with diffrent but less numbers.

Answer (score 1):

[Screenshot][https://i.stack.imgur.com/h28C2.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h28C2.png)

This is my code:

```
final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    color: Colors.white70,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: new GridView.count(
      childAspectRatio: screenWidth/180.0,          
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
      children: _buildFirdTitles(35),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use GridView.builder

Try this, use gridDelegate section to custom items height

Edit the parameter childAspectRatio

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
  crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
  // width / height: fixed for *all* items
  childAspectRatio: 0.75,
)
```

---

```
class ItemCardGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemCardGridView(
      {Key? key,
      required this.crossAxisCount,
      required this.padding,
      required this.items})
      // we plan to use this with 1 or 2 columns only
      : assert(crossAxisCount == 1 || crossAxisCount == 2),
        super(key: key);
  final int crossAxisCount;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  // list representing the data for all items
  final List<ItemCardData> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: padding,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
        // width / height: fixed for *all* items
        childAspectRatio: 0.75,
      ),
      // return a custom ItemCard
      itemBuilder: (context, i) => ItemCard(data: items[i]),
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will create`GridView` which takes up the remaining viewpoert height.

It will not overflow the viewport height.

Set `rows` and `cols` aoccordingly to your needs.

The example creates a *numpad* with 12 widgets.

```dart
class PasscodeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PasscodeWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      const int rows = 4;
      const int cols = 3;

      final double itemHeight = (constraints.maxHeight) / rows;
      final double itemWidth = constraints.maxWidth / cols;

      return Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
          child: GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
            crossAxisCount: cols,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(
              12,
              (index) => Text(
                index.toString(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ));
    }));
  }
}
```