# How to calculate childAspectRatio for GridView.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter

Grid of categories with image and category name displayed below the image

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
    future: categoriesService.getCategories(1),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        if (snapshot.error != null) {
          print('error ${snapshot.error}');
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        // YOUR CUSTOM CODE GOES HERE
        return Container(
          // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: GridView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              // childAspectRatio: 19 / 12,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            ),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Category category = snapshot.data[index];
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Image.network(
                      category.image,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(category.name)
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return new CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    });
```

}

My child item has an image and category name. as seen in the image, currently child item is overflowing and we cant see the category name below the image, and unable to remove top space between image and border.

[image]

Original design is here

[image]

Comment: child aspect ratio is basically width/height of the grid. So let's say you want the width of each grid to be 30 and the height to be 20, you would set the aspect ratio to be 3/2.

Comment: Not solved my problem yet. I have to show 1:1 image and at the bottom of each image want to add a container of full available width with 100 pixels height. Kindly suggest, how can we do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find a way to set aspect ratio of biggest child to our Grid view dynamicly.
how it work ?
First please Look at this answer for  . how we can find size of a widget during the build with `overlayEntery`

[How to get a height of a Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget)

after that we set the right aspect ratio (Measured with overlayEntery ) to our Grid View in childAspectRatio.

I hope this help you .

I Make an Example ...

https://dartpad.dev/4821d71ec618d7d1f1f92f27458fde61

---

---

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class GridItemModel {
  String longtext;
  GlobalKey itemKey;
  double width;
  double height;
  GridItemModel(this.longtext) {
    itemKey = GlobalKey();
  }
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }

}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _StateHomePage();
  }

}

class _StateHomePage extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // this first assign very important don't change it .
  // if you change this part overlayEntry cant find biggest widget correctly .(cant see not scrolled items.)
  // for test change to 1/1 and see what happening.
  var myDynamicAspectRatio = 1000 / 1;
  OverlayEntry sticky;
  List<GridItemModel> myGridList = new List();
  double maxHeight = 0;
  double maxWidth = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (sticky != null) {
      sticky.remove();
    }
    sticky = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => stickyBuilder(context),
    );

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Overlay.of(context).insert(sticky);
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      sticky.remove();
    });
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Grid List';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: myDynamicAspectRatio,
            children: List.generate(20, (index) {
              myGridList.add(new GridItemModel(longTextMaker(index)));
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    key: myGridList[index].itemKey,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      color: Colors.teal[index*100]
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Item $index' + myGridList[index].longtext,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
  String longTextMaker(int count){
    String  result = "longText";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < count; i++){
      result += "longText" ;
    }
    return result;
  }
  shouldUpdateGridList(){
    bool isChanged =false;
    for(GridItemModel gi in myGridList) {
      if(gi.width != null) {
        if (gi.height > maxHeight) {
          maxHeight = gi.height;
          maxWidth = gi.width;
          isChanged = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if(isChanged) {
        myDynamicAspectRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;
        print("AspectRatio" + myDynamicAspectRatio.toString());
    }
  }

  Widget stickyBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    for(GridItemModel gi in myGridList) {
      if(gi.width == null) {
        final keyContext = gi.itemKey.currentContext;
        if (keyContext != null) {
          final box = keyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          print(box.size.height);
          print(box.size.width);
          gi.width = box.size.width;
          gi.height = box.size.height;
        }
      }
    }
    shouldUpdateGridList();
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not solved my problem yet. I have to show 1:1 image and at the bottom of each image want to add a container of full available width with 100 pixels height. Kindly suggest, how can we do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

You could use the width and height of the device to calculate the aspect ratio dynamically. I have added a code sample based on yours showing how this could be done. Please note that you might need to adjust the provided aspect ratio slightly in order to fit your particular requirements.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Category {
  String name;
  String image;

  Category({this.name, this.image,});
}

class CategoriesService {
  Future<List<Category>> getCategories(int value) async {
    return <Category>[
      Category(
        name: 'FRESH CHICKEN',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: 'FRESH MUTTON',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: 'HALAL FROZEN FISH',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: '2X STORE',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: 'FROZEN NONVEG DELIGHTS',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: 'FROZEN VEG DELIGHTS',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: 'DAL & PULSES',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: 'SPICES',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
      Category(
        name: 'DRY FRUITS & NUTS',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/400/300',
      ),
    ];
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: CategoriesService().getCategories(1),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.error != null) {
              print('error ${snapshot.error}');
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            }
            // YOUR CUSTOM CODE GOES HERE
            return Container(
              // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: GridView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                ),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Category category = snapshot.data[index];
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Image.network(
                          category.image,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 8.0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          category.name,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return new CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: iPad Pro]
[image: iPhone X]
[image: Galaxy S5]

You might find the below answers useful for additional information regarding the aspect ratio of the `GridView` widget if you have not seen them already.

- [How to set Custom height for Widget in GridView in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48405123/how-to-set-custom-height-for-widget-in-gridview-in-flutter)
- [How to set grid view column height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602425/how-to-set-grid-view-column-height)
- [flutter how to give height to the childrens of GridView.Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612200/flutter-how-to-give-height-to-the-childrens-of-gridview-builder)

Comment: I have to show grid in 1:1 (width:height) ratio but height should have additional 100 pixels extra. eg. How can i do? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is a flutter package that solves this problem conveniently. Check it out at https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_height_grid_view. With this you can specify cross-axis count without respecting aspect ratio.

Comment: Easy to use and Configure

Comment: Should be marked as a correct answer.

Comment: this library requires you to define height ! where else in gridview we dont need to define the height

Answer (score 6):

For most use-cases where child height is static or need to be static,
please use `mainAxisExtent`.

Official docs

```
  /// The extent of each tile in the main axis. If provided it would define the
  /// logical pixels taken by each tile in the main-axis.
  ///
  /// If null, [childAspectRatio] is used instead.
  final double? mainAxisExtent;
```

Comment: The goal is to calculate the row height by the child content.
With mainAxisExtent you just set the fixed height. Not exactly what we needed.

Answer (score 5):

Child aspect ratio is basically width/height of the grid relative to the device.

So let's say you want the width of each grid to be 30 and the height to be 20, you would set the aspect ratio to be 3/2.

I suggest you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcnP3_mO_Ms) directly from the Flutter team. Although its about the AspectRatio widget, the part about setting the aspectRatio applies to this problem

Comment: Not solved my problem yet. I have to show 1:1 image and at the bottom of each image want to add a container of full available width with 100 pixels height. Kindly suggest, how can we do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can provide childAspectRatio in GridView.builder like this:

```
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate:
     SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
         crossAxisCount:3,childAspectRatio: (150.0 / 220.0)
     )
)
```

Comment: code block syntax is different in stackoverflow you can use help to view code block syntax

Answer (score 2):

The childAspectRatio value is a value for you to set the aspect ratio, if you want to make a neat square, you would use 1 and the width will be equal to the height.
if you want it to extend to the bottom, decrease the value.
sample

```
  childAspectRatio:0.9,
```

Answer (score 1):

((ScreenWidth - (left&right Padding + crossAxisSpace))/2)/ itemHeight

Eg.

- I have an item with height 241
- and gridview padding of left and right => 16 + 16
- and crossAxisSpace 9

I will calculate like this

```
double extraSpace = (16+16+9); 
aspectRatio : ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - extraSpace) / 2) / 241
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount( constraints.maxWidth,100),
    )
  };
);

  int crossAxisCount(double maxWidth, size) {
    int width= maxWidth~/ size;
    return width== 0 ? 1 : width;
  }
```