# gridview's all buttons should be fit inside its parent container in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am trying to make UI of calculator based on my drawing,

here I have divided screen in two expanded container, top one for output and bottom one for buttons...

in bottom container I have taken grid view to show all buttons,

I want to fit all button's in bottom area without having scrolling effect of grid view.

in my code...grid view not showing last row...I have to scroll down to view it...

[image]
here is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.orange,)),
            Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: buttons.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 4),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ButtonWidget(color: Colors.grey,
                          ontap: () {},
                          caption: buttons[index].toString(),
                          textcolor: Colors.black);
                    })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and here is button's class

```
class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final color;
  final textcolor;
  final String caption;
  final VoidCallback ontap;

  const ButtonWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.color,
      required this.ontap,
      required this.caption,
      required this.textcolor})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        ),
        child: Center(
            child: Text(
          caption.toString(),
          style: GoogleFonts.actor(fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Remove your `Expanded` for `GridView`.

2. Disable scrolling for GridView.
   Like this.

   ```
      GridView.builder(
       /// Add these two lines
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        /// Your code,
       ),
   ```

**Tip:**
If you don't wanna have small container on top, you can resize buttons' aspect ratio like this. But it will make buttons look a bit ugly.

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 4,
///Add this, tweak the value as you wish
childAspectRatio: 1.3,
),
```

**Have Fun!**

Comment: can u rate it if question is rated kind...

Comment: How do you know that you have to give 1.3 childAspectRatio?

Comment: Ahh, 1.3 is the sample answer. It may not work well on your screen. Bear with me as I'm too bored to calculate the aspect ratio :). If you wanna calculate it, here's the resource.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666204/how-to-calculate-childaspectratio-for-gridview-builder-in-flutter